# pipenv fails to create a virtual environment

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv

I am running Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL).

I open my VSCode using Ubuntu code in the terminal.

I have Python 3.8.2, pip 20.0.2 and pipenv  version 2020.6.2 installed.

I create a folder or my Python project and `cd` into it.

I type 'pipenv shell'.

I get the following error:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /home/user/Python/ExampleOne/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.8.2) to create virtualenv…
⠋ Creating virtual environment...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'

✘ Failed creating virtual environment
```

I do not seem to be able to find any information on the issue to resolve it.  How can I solve this issue or where might I look to understand it better?

Answer (score 8):

I have it working on a setup identical to yours (WSL1 running Ubuntu 20.04, pip 20.0.2, python 3.8.2, pipenv 2020.6.2). However, I also figured out how to replicate your problem so I think I know what's going on here. The error is actually a problem with virtualenv not pipenv itself (pipenv is built on virtualenv). You can verify this by trying to create a virtual env instead:

```
virtualenv my_env
```

or:

```
python -m virtualenv my_env
```

You should get the same error. This is only a problem in WSL and not in normal Ubuntu and it has to do with Window's path length limit (see [this github issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1769)). Luckily, if you install pipenv with pip instead of apt, it will use a shorter path that windows can deal with. Try this:

```
sudo apt autoremove pipenv
pip install pipenv
```

Now try to create your pipenv. Hopefully this solves your problem. It worked for me.

Comment: thanks! this solves my problem with Linux Ubuntu with deb packaged virtualenv + pipenv

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading the virtulenv version to 20.0.23 solves the problem for me

```
pip install virtualenv==20.0.23
```

Source : https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1873

Comment: Worked for me under WSL1!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pipenv install --python=/usr/bin/python3.6
pipenv --python /usr/bin/python3
```

Explanation: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3488.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It didn't seem to solve the issue for me, my which python result is usr/bin/python and my python --version is python 3.8.2 , if that gives anyone any help